# jquery ajaxStop event not working in IE9

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-9

We are trying to hide a loader icon after multiple async ajax calls are complete. Hence we need to use the ajaxStop event. But this event is not getting fired in ie9 (windows mobile phone). However, ajaxStart works. We are facing this issue only in ie9 in windows mobile phone. It works in IE9 and IE8 in the desktop versions. We're using jquery version 1.7.

Following is the code snippet -

```
$(document).ajaxStop( function(){
    $('#loader').hide();
});
```

Is there anything we are missing ?

Comment: I guess the code should be $.ajaxStop( function(){ ... });

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan, I think as of jQuery 1.8, `ajaxStop` should only be attached to the document like `$(document).ajaxStop(function(){})`

Answer (score 1):

Check  [this](http://jsfiddle.net/zbF9m/6/), but your [approach](http://jsfiddle.net/bsKPj/10/) is also working in IE 9.

```
//displays progress bar
$('.progress').ajaxStart(function () {
    $(this).show();
}).ajaxStop(function () {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to make  async:true..bocz on IE not able to handle  asyncs call.

check below code..here you have to set "async:true" ...so, your code should be below.

```
var selectRows = $('#rowed3').getGridParam('selarrrow');
$.each(selectRows,function (index,id) {
  $.ajax({                            
          url:'addSign',
          success: function (result) {                                                 
        $("#progressbar").progressbar('option','value',currPercent);
         },
          async:true,
          data:{
          'id':id,
          'details':sign
               },
       type:'post'
});
```